# Must French financial institutions know by law the salary of their customers?

Tags: privacy, finance, france

Must French financial institutions know by law the salary of their customers?

One of my French banks is asking this information from me and claims they have to do so by law (and I have "declare sur l'honneur", [i.e.](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=fr&tl=en&text=d%C3%A9claration%20sur%20l'honneur) make a sworn statement).

The best I have found so far is  [Code monétaire et financier - Article L561-4-1](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do;jsessionid=0ADBABC49937C586AE643A5E5103EBD1.tplgfr30s_2?idArticle=LEGIARTI000041577873&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006072026&dateTexte=20200603&categorieLien=id&oldAction=) but I haven't seen any mention yet on the salary.

Comment: My US credit card issuer is trying to make it look like the law requires them to know my salary, but it's not true.  They exaggerate the truth.  It wouldn't be too surprising if the same happens in other jurisdictions.